# How to get list of xbee devices in network using digi xbee Python

Tags: python, xbee

I have a `xbee` code running which has a scheduler scheduled to run every 1min. This scheduler queries the network and gets the `xbee` devices which are online. Below is the code:

```
def search_devices_in_nw():
    log_debug.error("Discovery process starting....")
    
    net = device.get_network()
    net.start_discovery_process(deep=True, n_deep_scans=1)
    while net.is_discovery_running():
        time.sleep(0.5)

    active_nodes = net.get_devices()
    print(active_nodes)


schedule.every(1).minutes.do(search_devices_in_nw)
while device.is_open():
    schedule.run_pending()
```

I have two devices in my `xbee` network and running this code, gives 2 mac address which is correct. But if I put one of the xbee device offline, it still gives result as 2 mac address online which is incorrect.

If I stop my code and restart it, then it shows 1 mac address online. I am not sure why the code is not working fine. Can anyone please help me in this. Please help. Thanks

Documentation page: https://xbplib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_doc/discovering_the_xbee_network.html#discovernetwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://xbplib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_doc/discovering_the_xbee_network.html#access-discovered-nodes), "All discovered XBee nodes are stored in the XBeeNetwork instance."

But you can also [clear the list of nodes](https://xbplib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_doc/discovering_the_xbee_network.html#clear-the-list-of-remote-xbee-nodes-from-the-xbee-network) with the `clear()` method on the `XBeeNetwork` object before initiating a new discovery:

```py
[...]

# Instantiate a local XBee object.
xbee = XBeeDevice(...)

[...]

# Get the XBee network object from the local XBee.
xnet = xbee.get_network()

# Discover XBee devices in the network and add them to the list of nodes.
[...]

# Clear the list of nodes.
xnet.clear()

[...]
```